# Python/Django random DB query results due to "Default argument value is mutable" in method

Tags: python, django, pycharm, mutable

I encountered a bug in my Django app yesterday and even though I fixed it since, I still do not understand its cause, neither how I resolved it.

Well, actually I found the root cause while writing this question, thanks to SO "Questions with similar titles" feature. See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Buuut, I still don't understand how could that affect my app in the way it affected it. So, let's dig in.

I have a web page, which display a list of items. I query those items through the `Model.get` method, from the views.py file. Nothing out of the ordinary, basically fetching the DB from the model, calling the model from the view and providing a variable with the fetched values to the template.

When using the faulty source code, I would refresh the page and the items would randomly either appear, or disappear. I figured the DB query would either return the items, or return an empty list.

Here is the faulty source code (model.py):

```
  @classmethod
  def get(cls, school=None, additional_filters={}):
    if school:
      additional_filters['school'] = school

    return MyModel.objects.filter(
      **additional_filters
    )
```

And here is how I fixed it:

```
  @classmethod
  def get(cls, school=None, additional_filters=None):
    if not additional_filters:
      additional_filters = {}

    if school:
      additional_filters['school'] = school

    return MyModel.objects.filter(
      **additional_filters
    )
```

I fixed it this way because PyCharm IDE told me there was something wrong `Default argument value is mutable` and since I couldn't explain the bug at all, I followed its recommendations.

But I still don't understand why. And even now, after reading ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) I still don't.

I understand now that the `additional_filters` were modified at every call due to the way Python handles default function arguments in memory.

What I don't explain is the side effect of this behaviour. Why did the query returned either the proper items or an empty set? Especially considering the code wasn't providing any `additional_filters`, meaning the only added item in `additional_filters` was `school` which was always the same at every query.

That's the part I really don't understand. All my calls to this method were of the form `Model.get(request.context.school)`, and since `additional_filters` is a map and not an array, it should always have contained the same value within.

This bug took me a while to figure out, because I couldn't reproduce it on my local environment nor in the staging environment, it affected only the production environment and made it very very difficult to locate.

Comment: Are you by any chance running your project in multiple processes in your production environment? Also does your staging environment differ from the production environment and if so how?

Comment: @FynnBecker The staging and production don't differ at all. They're hosted on the same server, connected to a different DB but the DB version is the same for both. Django is running in FCGI mode. I don't know if that means multiple processes though.

Comment: As a general rule, consider that a production setup for a django (or any wsgi app FWIW) project WILL run in multiprocess mode - and we're talking long running processes here, not "one shot" processes à la PHP. IOW, __any__ kind of mutable global state (mutable default arguments are just one example of mutable global state) must be avoided in such applications (this also applies to any code at a module or class top-level).

Comment: This actually explains why I couldn't reproduce the bug neither in development nor in staging environment, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

FCGI maintains a pool of processes. Each of the pool members has an empty dict as a default keyword argument.
You are initially lucky and the requests reach the processes with unchanged empty dict.
But whenever a request hits the process which already altered this dictionary, then it's not an empty dict anymore - your filters accumulate.